# Using open source resources in application

Tags: ios

Im about to submit my first application. I have used a few open source classes. Do i need to include any license or anything? I dont have any idea about the application submission process in app store.
Any feedback or past experience about submitting apps to apple without any hassle would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this help you https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each open source project will have its own license, which will identify what you need to do before submitting your application. You can find more information on the different open source licenses [here](http://opensource.org/licenses).